# Problems using ArrayList with Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I've been trying to implement a super class to reduce the length of code in my program. The program is an activity planner, where the user will decide whether they want to input a Home, School or Other activity. Right now, I am trying to add a partially completed instance to an ArrayList, and then I am trying to access that partially completed instance and give it a Start Time and End Time. Here is some of the code:

ArrayList is created by: `ArrayList<Activity> aList = new ArrayList();`

Main method:

```
System.out.println("*****************");
System.out.println("**Home Activity**");
System.out.println("*****************");
System.out.println("\n** Name **");
String tempName = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("**Description **");
String tempDescr = keyboard.nextLine();
aList.add(new Activity(tempName, tempDescr, "Home")); 
main.startTime(aList, listCount); // This line is where I get my error
main.endTime(aList, listCount);
// Methods aren't static so I need instance of class (main)
```

Further down is my startTime method:

```
// Creates a startTime for the instance
public void startTime(ArrayList<Activity> list, int listCount)
    {
        DayPlanner main = new DayPlanner();

        System.out.println("\n******Start Time*******");
        int intYear = main.yearInput();
        String tempMonth = main.monthInput();
        int intDay = dayInput();
        int intHour = hourInput();
        int intMinute = minuteInput();

        list.get(listCount).setStart(tempMonth, intDay, intYear, intHour, intMinute);
        // Line above is also where I get my error
    }
```

setStart is in my Activity Class:

```
public class Activity {

    protected String type;
    protected String activityName;
    protected Time startTime; // Default Time
    protected Time endTime; // Default Time
    protected String activityDescription;

    public void setStart(String month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute)
    {
        this.startTime.setDate(month, day, year, hour, minute);
    }
```

And setDate is in my Time Class:

```
public void setDate(String month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute)
    {
        if (dateOK(month, day, year, hour, minute))
        {
            this.month = month;
            this.day = day;
            this.year = year;
            this.hour = hour;
            this.minute = minute;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("Improper date set. Please try again.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

I apologize for hopping around but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong! The problem I'm having is a **NullPointerException**.

Here is the output of my error. As you can see, I am only able to input up to the end of my Start Time, so when I try to assign the Start Time to the element in the ArrayList, something happens.

```
******Start Time*******
** Year ** 
2000
** Month ** 
august
** Day ** 
09
** Hour ** 
5
** Minute ** 
61
Not valid minute. Range is [0-59].
** Minute ** 
59
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pkg2430ass1.Activity.setStart(Activity.java:50)
    at pkg2430ass1.DayPlanner.startTime(DayPlanner.java:304)
    at pkg2430ass1.DayPlanner.main(DayPlanner.java:50)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: `startTime` is probably null. Post the code where you assign/initialize that variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @khelwood: Funny, and maybe true, but maybe a little to generic to keep "possible duplicate" at that level?

Comment: I've exhausted many options so I apologize if this is on a beginner level (because that's what I am). I added "this." to the beginning of my startTime, but that doesn't fix anything. **Edit**: Initializing the startTime and endTime fixed me issue. Thank you guys/girls!

Comment: @Plaidypus: If you use Eclipse or something similar, this can be a good practise for some debugging. Put a breakpoint somewhere in your program and step through the code and try to read your variables' values.

Comment: @mattias Not really. The entire contents of the post were irrelevant except that he/she was getting an NPE and didn't know what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected Time startTime; // Default Time
protected Time endTime; // Default Time
protected String activityDescription;

public void setStart(String month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute)
{
    this.startTime.setDate(month, day, year, hour, minute);
}
```

What you are outlining as `Default Time` is not working like this. EVERY Object that is just `declared` is `null`. You need to `initialize` it, before acecssing its properties (or calling methods ON the object - you still can pass it arround as a parameter ofc)

```
protected Time startTime
```

is a declaration

```
protected Time startTime = new Time();
```

is a declaration followed by initialization. Until you initialize an object it is `null` and cannot be used for access unless a value has been assigned to that declaration.

if you don't want to initialize an object unless you really need it, you should consider using:

```
public void setStart(String month, int day, int year, int hour, int minute)
{
    if (this.startTime == null){
       this.startTime = new Time();
    }
    this.startTime.setDate(month, day, year, hour, minute);
}
```

ps.: Depending on what kind of `Time` Class you are using, there might be no Constructor without arguments.

Comment: Dammit! I must have deleted that: 'new Time();' when I was getting rid of excess code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with `startTime.setDate(month, day, year, hour, minute);`

Are you sure startTime is ever initialized?